# 'Unable to open WampServer's config file, please change path in index.php file' not opening localhost in browser

Tags: xampp

Recently I've been using WAMP server for my project. But due to some reason I need to switch to XAAMP server, so I uninstalled WAMP server and installed XAAMP server.

But when I open localhost in my browser it says:

> Unable to open WampServer's config file, please change path in index.php file

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem - check your www folder - delete index.php

Edit: The index.php is an unnecessary default home page for Wamp server which will cause the error when running from an XAAMP htdocs folder. In other words, your localhost is working, you've just got an index.php file from the old WAMP install.

Comment: Wow are you serious? It's a webserver - his problem is that he copied the www folder from Wamp to XAAMP - the index.php is a useless default home page for Wamp server which will cause the error when running from a XAAMP htdocs folder - I'm trying to help people here and you're voting me down - great job, thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 4):

you can edit your index.php and if you move it from one place to another, just change it like this:

> $wampConfFile = 'c:/wamp/wampmanager.conf';
>
> $aliasDir = 'c:/wamp/alias/';
>
> $vhostsDir = 'c:/wamp/vhosts/';

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error today. I realized I had uploaded my main's localhost index.php instead of the one in my webpage's folder.
So just make sure you're pointing at your correct localhost folder before uploading the index.php. Problem solved!